# How to enable suexec on a virtual host?

Tags: php, apache, suexec

I'm using Apache2.2 and FastCgi to run PHP code (with php-fpm).

My FCGI config is the following and works fine:

```
User apache
Group apache

LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so

FastCgiIpcDir /var/run/mod_fastcgi
FastCgiConfig -idle-timeout 20 -maxClassProcesses 1

AddHandler php-script .php
Action php-script /php5-fcgi
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

<Location "/php5-fcgi">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
</Location>
```

My Virtual host is configured as following and works fine too:

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XXX.XXX:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/apache/test"
    ServerName my.domain.com
    ErrorLog  /srv/apache/test/logs/test.log
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    LogLevel debug

    <Directory "/srv/apache/test/www">
        Options +Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


    Alias /php5-fcgi /var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600

    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/test">
        Options +ExecCGI
        SetHandler fastcgi-script
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My phpinfo() on my test page is shown. Now I would like to make it working with Apache's Suexec mod. So I add following lines to apache config:

```
# Into my virtualhost config
SuexecUserGroup www-test www-test

# Into my fastcgi config
FastCgiWrapper On
```

Then I chown to `www-test` user my fcgi script (`/var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi`) and my document root (`/srv/apache/test`).

I restart httpd and php-fpm services, I refresh my test page, and I got an error 500 with following logs:

```
==> /var/log/httpd/error_log <==
suexec failure: could not open log file
fopen: Permission denied
[Tue Nov 10 21:35:48 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi" (pid 29704) terminated by calling exit with status '1'
[Tue Nov 10 21:35:53 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi" (uid 505, gid 506) restarted (pid 29711)

==> /srv/apache/test/logs/test.log <==
[Tue Nov 10 21:36:05 2015] [error] [client 90.XXX.30.XX] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (20 sec)
[Tue Nov 10 21:36:05 2015] [error] [client 90.XXX.30.XX] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi"
```

Do you have an idea of the configuration I may missed?

---

Edit : I've edit one of my Vhost directive as following:

```
 FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -user www-test -group www-test
```

Now my test page is working, but I execute a `whoiam` command with php and I get the apache user instead of my Suexec user (www-test).

Do you have any idea of the reason my Suexec config doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

PHP FPM needs to be configured to use a specific [user](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#user).

Make sure the value in your pool configuration for `user` matches the Unix user you want PHP to execute as.  Usually it defaults to `www-data` but this may have changed to `www-user` depending on how you compiled PHP.